# QGIS WMS ver 1.3.0 Exception with GeoServer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms

I'm trying to load WMS layers from a local GeoServer into QGIS so that I can edit them. I can access and edit the same layers if I access them directly from a PostGIS database. However, trying to load them as WMS layers in QGIS fails with an XML Parsing Exception:

```
 <<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0"    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas /wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">   <ServiceException>
  javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Translator error
Translator error
Error occurred trying to write out metadata for layer: Pk50095
Unable to acquire a reader for this coverage with format: WorldImage
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
Tried URL: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

In addition, when I try to access the `GetCapabilites` URL directly, an XML Parsing error is generated for WMS ver 1.3.0. However, version 1.1.1 GetCapabilities URL executes fine.

Any idea on what may be wrong with my server installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known [issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-4544) with one of the sample layers on some systems, just delete that layer (Pk50095) from your server.

Comment: It works fine after deleted all the canned layers. Thanks a lot.